# Excel Solver (Way to add column of Constraints)

Tags: excel, constraints, linear-programming, solver

I have an excel sheet where I have typed out all of my constraints in a column. All the constraints are simple comparisons...ex `=A1>=B1` There are 72 constraints. Is there a way in solver to get around typing out all 72 constraints?
Could I, for example, write out a formula in a cell A74 saying `=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A73,"TRUE")<>72,0,1)` and then as a constraint in Solver say `"A74 = 1"`?

I'm just trying to figure out a way to utilize my column of constraints without having to retype them all into Solver. Thanks!

Picture of Column:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with VBA. Here is an example:

```
SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$22", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$E$24"
```

<= is relation 1 and >= is relation 3.

So you could define an int for the relation type and 2 strings for the other parts, then create a loop that goes through the cells and parses them into the 3 parts, using an if-else to define the relation int based on which symbol is found. Then if you change them you just run the macro again. You may also want to start your macro with:

```
SolverReset
```

so that it clears out the existing settings, otherwise you will end up with lots of duplicates.

Comment: Genius, thank you so much. Don't know why I didn't think of this.You saved me so much time as well as giving me much more control of the problem.